# How to polulate Child object field from a VF page standard controller of the Master Object

Tags: visualforce

have a Visual force page that overrides the "Close Case button" on case details page.VF page uses case standardController.I want to populate CaseComment.commentbody field of the  from this VF page. CaseComment is a Child object of Case.Sample code is as below

`<apex:page standardController="Case">
   <apex:form>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Postback_Options__c}" />
   <apex:inputField value="{!CaseComment.CommentBody}" label="Internal Comments" />
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>`

This throws an error 
Unknown property 'CaseStandardController.CaseComment'

Can Somebody please help me out.

Comment: Seems like you have missed the code. edit the question and add it

Answer (score 1):

`CaseComment` is separate object in salesforce.
So I suggest you use either standard controller extension or custom controller.

But If you want or have to use only standard controller here is some code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
   <apex:form>
       <apex:repeat value="{!Case.CaseComments}" var = "cc">
           <apex:inputField value="{!cc.CommentBody}" label="Internal Comments" />
       </apex:repeat>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<apex:inputField>` can only be used with SObject fields as per the documentation. Your `Case.CaseComments` returning a `List`. So you have to iterate through the list to access child fields.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Case.CaseComments}" var = "child">
    <apex:inputField value="{!child.CommentBody}" label="Internal Comments" />
</apex:repeat>
```

NOTE: Make sure to check the child relationship name in the `WSDL` for safe side.

Comment: I want to insert CaseComment.CommentBody ,not just iterate through them

Comment: In that case it's better to go for a custom controller. Because later on also you may need to include some logic.

Comment: Yes . developing a custom Controller works

Comment: Cool! It's better to having a custom controller for a frequently accessing page because those are having a higher possibility of requirement change :)